# Need to reverse latitude & longitude and get types of them with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in excel contain latitude and longitude. I need to Know what the types of lat and lon in column type. I used GeoPy to reverse lat and lon but I got just address. and need to get types also.
for example

```
import pandas as pd 
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
df = pd.read_excel("MyExcel_file.xlsx")
df["Geo"] = df["lat"].astype(str)+ ',' + df["lon"].astype(str)
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp", timeout=10)
rgeocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=0.001)
```

and apply my code in address column and its working fine but i can not find the types

```
df['address'] = df['Geo'].apply(rgeocode)
```

| latitude | longitude | address | types |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 49.789 | 6.06569 |  |  |

i need the output types for example hospital or house, Building, pharmacy etc..

| latitude | longitude | address | types |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 49.789 | 6.06569 | Stralauer Allee, Fhain, Friedrichshain-Kreuzberg | hospital |

i hope every thing its clear.
any help will be great.
best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can access the type in the full `json` response that can be accessed with the key `raw`. To wrap it in a function that populates both columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'latitude': 49.789, 'longitude':6.06569}])
df["Geo"] = df["latitude"].astype(str)+ ',' + df["longitude"].astype(str)
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp", timeout=10)
rgeocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=0.001)

def get_data(coordinates):
    location = rgeocode(coordinates)
    return pd.Series([location.address, location.raw['osm_type']])

df[["address", "types"]] = df['Geo'].apply(get_data)
```

Result:

|  | latitude | longitude | Geo | address | types |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 49.789 | 6.06569 | 49.789,6.06569 | Atelier communal, 9, Rue du Fossé, Bissen, Canton Mersch, 7772, Lëtzebuerg | way |